# Pressure cooking for one?

Tags: recipe-scaling, pressure-cooker

I just got myself a pressure cooker, one of those modern ones with both "sautee inside the cooker" functions.

The problem is I'll be cooking pretty much for myself, and that most recipes I saw are for 4-6 people. The pressure cooker itself looks like it's meant to be used for no less than 1 portion.

My question is, would halving/thirding/quartering the recipe still be alright with these huge pressure cookers? I imagine with less water, the meats will be less likely to be covered fully, and things like that. Would the pressure just magically take care of everything, and cook things evenly?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I use the pressure cooker for myself, and to me 4-6 people just means 4-6 meals for one person... Which is great if you're more into practicality and time saving, like me, but may not be so great if you don't like eating cold food.

Comment: You can't refrigerate leftovers and microwave it for your lunches?

Answer (score 5):

You should never use less liquid than is recommended by the manufacturer.

If you use less you run the risk of boiling your food dry or burning it since the level of heat to maintain the pressure may increase.

Get used to leftovers.  You can cook several portions reserve the excess for later use.  This will save you time and money.  I usually will cook a whole chicken and shred the meat and use it for several meals until it's gone.

Comment: Good answer! I like having leftovers for convenience, especially if you have a freezer it can be a big time-saver.